# CSS : adjust a div height according to the neighbor div in a flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I have a problem I don't manage to solve by myslef, even though it looks simple.

On a web page, I have a flex container div, which contains 2 other div.
The first div is nothing else than a space reserved to trigger some action when the mouse is over(typically, open a menu).
The second div is dynamically populated with elements according to some parameters and user actions. (For example, the user clicks on a button which trigger the creation of a new textarea field).

So, the second div may become higher and higher.

Is there a way to have the first div automatically following the height of the second div, even if the second div overflows ?

Here is a basic example of what I did :

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id="div1">
    -
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#div1 {
    background-color: mediumblue;
  width: 20px;
  color: mediumblue;
}

.yellowDiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid 2px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

In this example, the yellow div simulates the one which is dynamically populated, and the blue div simulates the one I want to use to trigger the opening of my menu.

Is there a way to achieve this with flexbox ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

Comment: hi, check this out mabye its what youre looking for: https://newbedev.com/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-div-dynamically-based-on-another-div-using-css

Answer (score 1):

Not with `flex`, but you should try doing it with `grid`.

```css
#wrapper {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 100px;
  height: min-content;
}

#div1 {
    background-color: mediumblue;
  width: 20px;
  color: mediumblue;
}

.yellowDiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid 2px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id="div1">
    -
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>

    <div class="yellowDiv">
      One element
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check the above code snippet.

> The theory around the concept: If you don't specify a specific value of `grid-template-rows`, then it will make all the columns of maximum size.

Do let me know if you got a problem with it :)